# Perl: Type first elements in a sorted hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following:

```
.
.
.
foreach my $op(reverse sort {$count{$a} <=> $count{$b}} keys %count) {
       printf "%-25s %s\n", $op, $count{$op};
}
.
.
.
```

This basically types all the elements in my list sorted. I would only like to have the first three elements typed and not all of them, these three elements are the ones most repeated, i.e. have the highest count.

Please let me know if you would like me to share the rest of my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `$count{$a} <=> $final{$b}` correct? Not `$count{$a} <=> $count{$b}` ?

Comment: Usually just use a counter, break the loop (using `last`) if this counter reach the number you need.

Comment: @tivn sorry that was an error done by me when I copied the code here. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could indeed us a counter.

```
my $limit = 3;
for my $op ( reverse sort { $count{$a} <=> $count{$b} } keys %count ) {
    printf "%-25s %s\n", $op, $count{$op};
    last if !--$limit;
}
```

You could use a list slice if you're guaranteed at least three elements.

```
for my $op ( ( reverse sort { $count{$a} <=> $count{$b} } keys %count )[0..2] ) {
    printf "%-25s %s\n", $op, $count{$op};
}
```

It's a little longer if you can't make sure guarantee.

```
my @ops = reverse sort { $count{$a} <=> $count{$b} } keys %count;
splice(@ops, 3) if @ops > 3;
for my $op (@opts) {
    printf "%-25s %s\n", $op, $count{$op};
}
```

(`if @ops > 3` prevents a warning in older versions of Perl.)

Comment: Oh, that's the correct way to write it! Tried something similar but got a syntax error. Thank you!

Comment: The parens are required when doing a list slice.

Comment: `$#ops = 3-1 if ..;` is perhaps better than splice.

Comment: @Сухой27, I prefer `splice(@ops, 3);` over `$#ops = 3-1 if @opts > 3;`. A lot. [LOL, that accidental typo kinda proves the point.]

Comment: imo, even a slice is better than splice `@ops = @ops[0..2] if ..; :)`

Comment: I disagree. I think truncating (`splice(@ops, 3);`) is better than creating duplicating magic numbers and replacing the array with copies of the scalars already at the right position in the array (`@ops = @ops[0..2] if @ops > 3;`). The latter is more expensive, more error prone and requires more reading.